# How to unzip any zip file using File Connector in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to unzip a zip file which may be of any name. Below is my code:-

```
<proxy name="Unzip" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <fileconnector.unzip>
            <source>file:///D:/AfterProcess/.*\.zip</source>
            <destination>file:///D:/001/</destination>
        </fileconnector.unzip>
        <respond></respond>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
```

But it is not able to unzip it. If I try by giving the file name as below:-

```
<source>file:///D:/AfterProcess/Hello.zip</source>
```

then it is working. How to unzip a file if I don't know name of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use regex in the source when unzipping. If you could then what happens if there are multiple files that match?

If you know that the zip file is always going to be in that directory then you can use the file connector search to find out the name of the file.

```
<fileconnector.search>
    <source>file:///D:/AfterProcess/</source>
    <filePattern>.*\.zip</filePattern>
    <recursiveSearch>False</recursiveSearch>
</fileconnector.search>
```

The search will return the following if it is the only zip file in the directory.

```
<fc:result xmlns:fc="http://org.wso2.esbconnectors.FileConnector">
    <fc:file>/AfterProcess/Hello.zip</fc:file>
</fc:result>
```

From there you can feed the path into the unzip function. You will need to prefix it the search result with `file:///D:` to make it a absolute path again.

```
<fileconnector.unzip>
    <source xmlns:fc="http://org.wso2.esbconnectors.FileConnector">{fn:concat('file:///D:', //fc:result/fc:file/text())}</source>
    <destination>file:///D:/001/</destination>
</fileconnector.unzip>
```

Comment: Hi, For <fileconnector.search> it is giving the output as :- <ns:result xmlns:ns="http://org.wso2.esbconnectors.FileConnector">
   <ns:file>/AfterProcess/prac1.zip</ns:file>
</ns:result>

Comment: But at time of unzip it is giving the error saying:- "org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not find file with URI "/AfterProcess/prac1.zip" because it is a relative path, and no base URI was provided.". What should I correct?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know you are not getting the return value I was expecting. I have updated my answer to match.

Comment: Thanks for updating, it worked perfectly. I was thinking to concat, but was writing the syntax wrong for concat function. Thanks.